# After reading a fact from a copyrighted textbook, does asking about that fact on a public forum infringe copyright?

Tags: copyright, india

When someone reads a line or a paragraph in a copyrighted textbook that explains a fact T, then wonders why T occurs, is asking a question (on Stack Exchange or another public forum) such as: "Why does T occur?" an infringement of copyright law? What if topic T was not very obscure?

Comment: Subrat, I am sorry to say this but I would downvote your question if I could - you do not seem to have researched the definition of 'copyright' or 'copyrighted'. I recommend you start by googling something like "what is copyright".

Comment: Not sure why this has gotten the upvotes it has.  It shows no sign at all of any research or effort, and must be a duplicate since copyright is such a consistent theme here.  What's next?  Does knowledge infringe on copyright?  @Spike0xff, i gotcha covered...

Answer (score 27):

In most copyright law (India is no exception), facts and ideas cannot be copyrighted. A particular expression of a fact or idea (i.e. the words used to say it) can be copyrighted, but not the underlying thought. The fact that I wrote this answer, for example, means I own the copyright to these particular words describing copyright law, but that certainly does not mean I own the copyright on the very idea of copyright law, and that no one may discuss copyright law without my approval.

Comment: But note that _collections_ of facts can be copyrighted in many jurisdictions under database rights, even if none of the individual facts can be copyrighted. The fact that I’m 175cm high cannot be copyrighted, but a database of the heights of 1 million people can.

Comment: @MikeScott The fact that you're 175cm is personal information, which in Europe has much stricter rules than copyright. Now that I've posted this comment, if you're in Europe you can send an email to stackexchange and request that they censor my comment to erase your height from it.

Comment: @MikeScott So to infringe that copyright, the perpetrator would have to have memorized the entire (or a significant portion) of the collection. There are few people who could memorize a big chunk of a phone book.

Comment: @Barmar No, the perpetrator might for example scrape the data from a website. Or just purchase one copy of the database and then start making and selling their own copies of it. No memorisation required. Do you have to memorise a novel to infringe on its copyright?

Comment: @Barmar Memorization *never* amounts to copyright infringement, the "copy" in your head is exempt. Such infringement would also be completely impractical as it is neither provable (how would the court scan your mind?) nor avoidable (one would have to refrain from consuming media completely, as any memory is to be avoided).

Comment: @Chieron Of course. I meant reciting what you memorized.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, yes. 
Though, I wonder what makes the collection of data copyrightable. The database *structure* could be copyrightable, but the facts themselves? They are protected as company secrets or the GDPR, but I do not see, how copyright comes into this.

Comment: @Chieron I think it depends on the jurisdiction. In the US the [Feist case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.) is the precedent that determined that raw information is not copyrightable. Copyright requires creativity, so you can copyright if you express editorial judgement, or use creative presentation (but not simple mechanical sorting, e.g. alphabetizing is not creative).

Comment: @Barmar, "*I meant reciting what you memorized.*" Merely reciting something from memory is not a copyright violation because you are not creating a copy.

Comment: @MichaelHall The original asks about posting the memorized material online. Also, reciting aloud could be a public performance, which is protected by copyright.

Comment: @Barmar, then you should have specified publishing, or a putting on a public recitation.  And I used the word "merely" for a reason.

Answer (score 8):

Nuclear Hoagie's answer correctly notes that repeating the ideas and knowledge of facts is not copyright infringement when expressed in your own words.

Further, if you decide to include a short citation from a published book in your own text, that is normally covered by [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) or [right to quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_quote) rules in the copyright law. In most countries, it is enough if the citation is short in length compared to the whole work, and it is directly related to your own work. In every case it is necessary to credit the original author of the citation.

I'm not familiar with India's copyright law in particular, but this seems to fall under the "criticism or review" and "personal use" categories in [Exceptions To Infringement Under Copyright Act, 1957](https://copyright.gov.in/Exceptions.aspx).